# How to group documents by hours in elastic search aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I tried to group my document by hours for a day through aggregation but always get exception "expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]"? What's the problem?

```
{
   "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "range" : {
          "timestamp" : {
            "from" : "2017-08-14 00:00:00",
            "to" : "2017-08-15 00:00:00",
            "include_lower" : true,
            "include_upper" : true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "result_by_hours": {
      "histogram": {
        "script": "doc.timestamp.date.getHourOfDay()",
        "interval": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I expect is to return the number of documents for each hour on yesterday. How can I use dynamic real time instead of "2017-08-14 - 2017-08-15"?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: 2nd try also failed :(
  "aggs" : {
    "result_by_hours" : {
      "date_histogram" : {
        "field" : "timestamp",
        "interval" : "hour",
        "format" : "k"
      }
    }
  }

Comment: what is the es version ?

Comment: The ES version is 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Depending on ES version, you can use range filter/query relative to "now", ex now-1d/d will go 1 day back in time.

See examples at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html

As for the aggs you can also group by interval of for instance an hour using date_histogram with interval
In ES 5.5:
Query:

```
"range" : {
          "timestamp" : {
            "gte" : "now-1d/d,
            "lte" : "now/d"
          }
        }
```

Aggs:

```
 {
        "aggs" : {
            "values_over_time" : {
                "date_histogram" : {
                    "field" : "timestamp",
                    "interval" : "1h"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```